# changing h2 to mysql db on spring boot get error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, innodb, h2

I’m working on spring boot v2.3.5.

My problem is I set my variable
“hibernate.dialect” to MySQL5InnoDBDialect.

Then error is returned that MySQL syntax error when creating table.

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE A (ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ACCESS_TOKEN VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, CREATE_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL, REFRESH_TOKEN VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, USER_NO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) ENGINE=[*]INNODB"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement
```

But actually when i copied that command, it works. Plus, when I change the option from Innodb to H2 db, it works.

Any ideas with my problems?

Comment: have you also updated other connection properties like url, username, password...?

Comment: No, I'm just using default database. "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
my test code is working on H2 db, but when I changed my h2 db to using Mysql syntax, it doesn't work

Comment: How about chaning drive like this:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching your datasource between different dababases you have to update configuration properly. From available information you have provided I assume you need to updated it as follows:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDbName
spring.datasource.username = dbUsername
spring.datasource.password = dbPassword
```

please update url, username and password according to your environment